# How to get a float result from a HELM template division operation?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In helm, there are Math functions https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#math-functions and they have a `div` function which divides integer! but is there any way to get a decimal result out of division?

I need to get a unit interval out of the percentage.

So if the value is 90 I need to get 0.9, if it is 2 I need 0.02.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? To calculate the percentage of some value, maybe you can multiply by the value and divide by 100.

Comment: I am creating a datadog alerting, and it receives a unit interval which is a number between 0 and 1, for percentage, but for readability, I need to send percentage and convert it to unit interval in the template

Comment: Is the percentage value integer? Are you allowed to register new, custom functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no functions available in Helm templates which support floating point division.

Easiest would be to register a custom function which does the conversion and division.

If you can't register your custom functions, there is still a way to do this with what's available in Help templates.

You may construct a string that contains the floating point representation of the expected result, and use the `float64` Helm template function to parse that string into a `float64` value.

Here's how it may look like:

```
{{ printf "%d.%02d" (div . 100) (mod . 100) | float64 }}
```

If the percent is `100`, the first digit will be `1`, `0` otherwise. Then follows a dot and the 2-digit value of the percent, so using this format string, you'll get the floating point representation. Passing this to the `float64` function, it'll parse it and return it as a `float64` value.

Testing it:

```
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "div":     func(a, b int) int { return a / b },
        "mod":     func(a, b int) int { return a % b },
        "float64": func(s string) (float64, error) { return strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64) },
    }).Parse(`{{range .}}{{ printf "%d.%02d" (div . 100) (mod . 100) | float64 }}
{{end}}`))

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, []int{0, 2, 90, 100}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Output (try it on the Go Playground):

```
0
0.02
0.9
1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked. I only tried the second suggestion because I cannot register my function. Thanks a lot. I hope others would benefit from this solution. I wonder why there is no direct way to divide float?