# float division in Go template

Tags: go, grafana, go-templates

In grafana (which uses go templates for Loki line templating), I would like to divide a field (milliseconds) and get a float result.

Here is what I'd like to do :

```
| logfmt | line_format "{{ .microsec | float64 | div 1000 | printf \"%6.3f\" }}ms"
```

However, this obviously doesn't work because `div` is the integer divide function.

The following does work (but does not divide the number) :

```
| logfmt | line_format "{{ .microsec | float64 | printf \"%8.0f\" }}μs"
```

How can I get my output in millisecond format ?

EDIT :
There is also a `divf` function, but the documentation says "Perform integer division". And I get very strange results with it (so I'm not sure how to use it) :

```
{{ .microsec | float64 | printf \"%8.0f\" }}μs {{  .microsec | float64 | divf 1000 | printf \"%6.3f\" }}ms?divf
6332μs   0.158ms?divf
22959μs  0.044ms?divf 
7034μs   0.142ms?divf
```

Comment: Isn't there a [`divf`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/mathf.html) function?

Comment: divf returns a decimal result, so it basiically the same that div  (tbh, it gives weird results)

Comment: `divf 10 2 4` returns `1.25`. Did you convert the input to `float64`?

Comment: "divf 10 2 4 returns 1.25" is exactly what is quoted in the documentation, but did you try it youself ? I edited my question with my unsuccessful trials with divf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grafana docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/template/) state that:

> All [sprig functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) have been added to the template stage in Loki 2.3(along with function described below).

And the [Float Math Functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/mathf.html) include a `divf` function to perform floating point division.

Quoting from [`text/templates`: Pipelines:](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Pipelines)

> A pipeline may be "chained" by separating a sequence of commands with pipeline characters '|'. In a chained pipeline, **the result of each command is passed as the last argument of the following command**. The output of the final command in the pipeline is the value of the pipeline.

So when you do:

```
{{ .microsec | float64 | divf 1000 | float64 | printf "%6.3f" }}ms
```

You're actually dividing 1000 with the microsec value. Obviously you want the opposite, so simply do:

```
{{ divf .microsec 1000 | printf "%6.3f" }}ms
```

Also note that where floating point division is not supported (meaning there's no `divf` function), you can still do it with integer arithmetic.

```
{{ printf "%d.%03d" (div .microsec 1000) (mod .microsec 1000) | float64 }}ms
```

For more details, see [How to get a float result from a HELM template division operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942424/how-to-get-a-float-result-from-a-helm-template-division-operation/69943575#69943575)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @icza, I tried again around "divf" function, and the following works :

```
{{ divf .microsec 1000 | printf \"%6.3f\" }}ms
```

I still don't understand at this point why the following seems to return incorrect results :

```
{{ .microsec | float64 | divf 1000 | float64 | printf \"%6.3f\" }}ms
```

I also don't know where the documentation about `divf` can be found.